# Java Generic puzzle

Tags: java, generics, refactoring

I have Java classes:

```
abstract class Parent {
    abstract void test(Object pObject, Map<String, Object> pData);
}

public class Test extends Parent {
    @Override
    void test(Object pObject, Map<String, Object> pData) {
    }
}
```

And would like to refactor the code to:

```
abstract class Parent<T> {
    abstract void test(T pObject, Map<String, Object> pData);
}

public class Test extends Parent {
    @Override
    void test(Object pObject, Map<String, Object> pData) {
    }
}
```

Eclipse (4.4.2 if it's matter) tells me that code in Test class is invalid (compile time errors) and correct `test()` method signature must be:

```
@Override
void test(Object pObject, Map pData) {
}
```

My question is WHY!?

Actually, real story is a bit longer. I've a lot of children class (like Test) and don't wish to change them and prefer to use generic (i.e. `<T>` class) for new children of Parent class. And in both cases second parameter of `test()` method must be `Map<String, Object>`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see to get to where you want is to keep the `Parent` class as it is and introduce another class that gives you the template capabilities like so:

```
abstract class TemplatedParent<T> {
    abstract void test(T pObject, Map<String, Object> pData);
}

abstract class Parent extends TemplatedParent<Object> {}
```

This way you can keep your old code, and new code that requires the template capabilities has to extend the `TemplatedParent` directly.

Comment: Nope. They can keep extending `Parent` and get the same method signature as before the refactoring.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is WHY!?

When you extend a **raw** version of `Parent`, then all the generic information within the class is just ignored. Therefore, you are extending a `Parent`, which looks like:

```
abstract class Parent {
    abstract void test(Object pObject, Map pData);
}
```

In order to *preserve* the type-parameters for the `Map` parameter, you can just specify that you're extending a `Parent<Object>`. Now this code should compile fine:

```
public class Test extends Parent<Object> {
    @Override
    void test(Object pObject, Map<String, Object> pData) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, unless going through all the `Test`-similar classes and manually refactor them, there's no other option.

Comment: Still this is the correct answer. If you like it or not ;) The only way around this I see to keep the signature (without template) of the parent class and introduce another class (e.g. TemplatedParent) that actually defines the test method and is extended by your "old" Parent class.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, `Parent` is a plain class and you have sub-clased it in the expected manner, all is good.

In the second example, instead of extending `Parent<T>` you have extended the generic erased `Parent` which removes all generics from the class even if they don't involve `T`.

try

```
public class Test extends Parent<Object> {
    @Override
    void test(Object pObject, Map<String, Object> pData) {
    }
}
```

Comment: And no way to do what I need? Keep old classes intact and make new one in generic way?

Comment: @FoxyBOA see my addition to my answer.

Comment: @FoxyBOA I am not saying you have to change old or new code, I am just telling you why it won't work. ;)

Comment: @FoxyBOA - we don't want to do a lot of things:) the right thing to do is to find all subclasses and add `<Object>` to them. it'll take you a few minutes.

Comment: @bayou.io - no. dependent projects. backports etc. Believe me it can take years :(

Comment: @FoxyBOA I suggest you leave anything which is already working, and only change what is not.